# Make first layer of AlexNet parallel in lua

Tags: lua, parallel-processing, deep-learning, layer, torch

I am trying to have parallel table for the first layer of Alexnet in Torch, Lua. I want to pass two Batches of RGB images to the network and then send the addition of them to the next layer. For example: suppose that I want to send images with 6 channels to the first layer of alexnet but in this case, I want to send two batches of 3 channels each to the first parallel layers , join them and then send the output to the next layer. 
the actual code is like this:

```
net = nn.Sequential()
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3,96,11,11,4,4,2,2))       
net:add(nn.SpatialBatchNormalization(96))
net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
net:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(3,3,2,2))                   
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(96,256,5,5,1,1,2,2))       
net:add(nn.SpatialBatchNormalization(256))
net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
net:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(3,3,2,2))                   
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(256,384,3,3,1,1,1,1))
```

and the code I thought it would work is :

```
net = nn.Sequential()
c = nn.ParallelTable()
c:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3,48,11,11,4,4,2,2)) 
c:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3,48,11,11,4,4,2,2))
net:add(c)
net:add(nn.JoinTable(1,8))
net:add(nn.SpatialBatchNormalization(96))
net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
net:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(3,3,2,2))
```

and the error I got is :

> In 1 module of nn.ParallelTable:
>   /torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cudnn/init.lua:171: assertion failed!

I was wondering where I am going wrong with this implementation and any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The actual code shows that the inputs have 18 channels, therefore you cannot use a `SpatialConvolution` with 3 input channels

Comment: It was my mistake. the actual code is 3 that will get input with 3 channels but now i want to give the model 2 batches of 3 channels images(i can give my model batches of 6 channels by changing 3 to 6 in the first layer but I want to give the network two batches of 3 channels instead of one batches of 6 channels)

Comment: what are the dimensions of the input tensor to your model?

Comment: The dimensions of the input tensor is  128* 3*227 * 227.

Comment: you are training on gpu? your model and input tensor are transformed into cuda model and tensor?

Comment: Yes I'm training on gpu. I am using Torchstarter code( https://github.com/cvondrick/torch-starter) i just want to change the first layer of the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is on the line `net:add(nn.JoinTable(1,8))`, it should be 3 instead of 8. This value is the number of dimensions (without counting the batch dimension as a dimension) of your input tensor. Here you feed your network with 3D images, then you should write `net:add(nn.JoinTable(1,3))`

I used the following code and all goes well

```
require 'nn'
require 'cutorch'
require 'cunn'
require 'cudnn'

net = nn.Sequential()
c = nn.ParallelTable()
c:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3,48,11,11,4,4,2,2)) 
c:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3,48,11,11,4,4,2,2))
net:add(c)
net:add(nn.JoinTable(1,3))
net:add(nn.SpatialBatchNormalization(96))
net:add(nn.ReLU(true))
net:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(3,3,2,2)) 

net:cuda()

input1 = torch.rand(128,3,227, 227):cuda()
input2 = torch.rand(128,3,227,227):cuda()

out = net:forward({input1, input2})

print(out:size())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I changed it to 3 and it worked.

Comment: @M.es if that solved your question, accept the answer to show everybody that the question is solved